# PostgreSQL 9.3.5 database restore error : plpgsql already exists

Tags: database, postgresql, backup, restore

I have a .net program to restore a PostgreSQL database backup. What it is doing is

```
1) Delete the existing database. 
2) Create it again.
3) Initialize some variables/properties.
4) Restore the database.
```

My problem is while I am trying to restore the PostgreSQL 8.3 database backup to PostgreSQL 9.3. While restoring i am getting the following error : **plpgsql already exists** so my program returns FAILURE as there is error.

If i do a `DROP EXTENSION 'plpgsql'` query after i create the new DB, restore is very successful.But, from my program, i can't do it or not willing to do it.

I know this is ignorable error, but, i need to make my program correct. How can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "i can't do it or not willing to do it"... Why not? What _are_ you willing/able to do?

Comment: Hi @NickBarnes Mine is a C# program, so i do not want to run DROP command every time. Now i have modified my program to accept cmdline args so it is working now.